# Placeholder not working in IE 11 when set using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a requirement where I have 6 read only html textbox and I need to set the placeholder dynamically using JQuery . The method I have used works fine in Chrome but doesn't work on IE 11.

```
$(".textBox").attr("placeholder", "Please Select Items");
```

Above should be the default placeholder and upon selection of multiple select  elements the count should be updated which I have written as below

```
$('.textBox').attr('placeholder',TempArray.length + " Items selected");
```

I have searched for the similar questions but does not seem to the relevant to my problem. Is there any alternative method in JQuery which can resolve the issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: could insert a plunker of your code so it would be easy to debug

Answer (score 1):

I tried below code in IE 11. Its works fine.

```
<input type="text" id="add_placeholder"  placeholder="please select" readonly></input>
<button id="click">Click me</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('#click').click(function(){
    $('#add_placeholder').attr('placeholder','name is inserted');
});
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ev4rg8ed/